# Someone else experienced boot failures with the 5.19.0-45-generic kernel version?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, kubuntu

I don't know when this version was installed. But yesterday the system send me a notice that thought to apply the update requires a system reboot.

I did this and after that, the system boot failed.

The grub screen appeared and after that returned the motherboard splash screen and then the screen did not change. But there was HDD activity as if the system was loading, only the screen did not change.

I (temporarily) solve this error with downgraded the kernel version to 5.19.0-43-generic.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed-hwe-5.19/+bug/2024943

Answer (score 0):

1. Try a `sudo apt install --reinstall <package_name>` of the non-working kernel. Review your output carefully for problems or errors that you need to fix before proceeding to Step 2.

That step alone might fix your problem. If not, then keep going:

2. If that doesn't work, then note the time, reboot into the broken kernel for a few minutes, then reboot into the working kernel. Check logs for the time that you were booted into the broken kernel. Note any errors or warnings that might assist troubleshooting.
3. Check the kernel bug reports at Launchpad.net to see if this exact reversion has already been reported. If so, subscribe to the bug. If your logs will assist troubleshooting, then *attach* your logfiles to the bug report. If the bug has not already been reported, then please report it (`ubuntu-bug linux`)

   Pro Tip: DON'T skip steps. Reporting a duplicate bug (or a bug report without adequate information) simply wastes a lot of time and effort, delaying a fix. The additional information from your logs might offer key insight, speeding up a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue!

For me, everything starts booting and then it hangs. I watched the startup output and it completely stops at a point, produces no output, and the HDD light blinks every 15 seconds.

Checking the log it seems to have something to do with initializing the NTFS drive I have but I am also a linux noob so I could be reading it wrong.

My solution was to just downgrade but if there is a pro that knows the proper solution I would appreciate it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here: after dist upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04, I had no graphics (nvidia drivers didn't work and crashed. Nouveau drivers still worked), no network (neither USB-LAN dongle, nor built in Wifi properly detected, no properly working touchpad, no bluethooth and many more ...) Kernel was 5.19.0-45-generic.

Grub still had a Linux 5.15.0-76-generic entry, which works fine ... now trying to downgrade kernels to bisect problem.

UPDATE: I collected kern.log logs from a boot with the new 5.19, and the old 5.15 kernel. There are no obvious errors in the 5.19 log, but comparing the logs reveals that the 5.15 kernel, at some point, starts initializaing a lot of USB devices etc, while there are no such messages in the 5.19 log (nor would these devices work)